# Should I pass and store class references or make methods to get them from a central class?

Tags: java, class

I have a main class branching off to different classes which handle certain things.

Sometimes some of the classes need a method from a different class.

Currently I'm declaring and initiating the classes in my main class and then passing these objects to other classes that need them.

Example 1:

```
public class Main extends plugin {

    private Walking walkClass;
    private Sitting sitClass;

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        walkClass = new Walking(this);
        sitClass = new Sitting(this, walkClass);
    }

    //Methods

}

public class Walking {

    Main mainClass;

    public Walking(Main mainClass) {
        this.mainClass = mainClass;
    }

    //Methods

}

public class Sitting {

    Main mainClass;
    Walking walkClass

    public Sitting(Main mainClass, Walking walkClass) {
        this.mainClass = mainClass;
        this.walkClass = walkClass;
    }

    //Methods

}
```

Is okay to do this, or will it be better to create methods in the Central class to give references to other classes? In regards to Memory and CPU usage and Java practices.

Edit:
I'm comparing it to something like this;

Example 2:

```
public class Main extends plugin {

    private Walking walkClass;
    private Sitting sitClass;

    private boolean started;

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        started = true;

        walkClass = new Walking();
        sitClass = new Sitting();
    }

    public boolean isStarted() {
        return started;
    }

    public Walking getWalking() {
        return walkClass;
    }
    public Sitting getSitting() {
        return sitClass;
    }

}

public class Walking {

    private Main mainClass;

    private boolean walking;

    public Walking(Main mainClass) {
        this.mainClass = mainClass;
        walking = mainClass.isStarted();
    }

    public boolean isWalking() {
        if (mainClass.isStarted() {
            return walking;
        }
    }

}

public class Sitting {

    Main mainClass;

    public Sitting(Main mainClass) {
        this.mainClass = mainClass;
    }

    public boolean isSitting() {
        return !mainClass.getWalking().isWalking();
    }

}
```

I'm just worried that if I do it like in Example 1 and I store too many references to other instances it'll take up more memory than doing doing it like in Example 2.

Then if I do it like in Example 2, I'm worried that calling a method will add additional CPU tick(s) over if I did it as Example 1. I have no formal education in Java so I have no idea.

Though the fact that people would consider Example 1 the best practice is encouraging.

Comment: You're not passing class references, but object references. Why wouldn't it be OK to do this? What would the alternative be? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is a common pattern called "Dependency Injection" and some would consider it best practice.  I wouldn't worry about memory or CPU usage unless you have measured your application e.g. with a profiler, and found an issue.

Comment: Your second example wouldn't compile, and doesn't make sense. And your worries about performance are imaginary. What you should worry about regarding performance is complexity of algorithms (O(n^2) vs. O(n)), the IO and the SQL queries. you're only speculating here, without any rational basis. Tryto make your code correct, and readable. That's what is important. If you have a performance problem, then measure toknow where it comes from.